# Retrieve View info from DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

maybe this is a trivial question for many of you...

My app has a TabControl defined as:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">

    <!--Bind the SelectionChanged event of the tab-->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedChangedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <!--This is How tab will look-->
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button Name="BtnCloseTab" 
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                        Margin="5,0,0,0" 
                        Padding="0"                         
                        Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
                                  {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, 
                                  Path=DataContext.CloseTabCommand}">
                    <Image Source="/EurocomCPS;component/Images/closeTab.png" Height="11" Width="11"></Image>
                </Button>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <!--This will be the content for the tab control-->
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl
              ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
              Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

</TabControl>
```

In the window ViewModel I have the following prop:

```
private ObservableCollection<Tab> _Tabs;

public CPSViewModel()
{
  _Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>();
}

public ObservableCollection<Tab> Tabs
{
  get { return _Tabs;}
  private set 
  {
    _Tabs = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Tabs");
  }
}
```

Now, when a new Tab is created, the following DataTemplateSelector is called:

```
  class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
  {
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      if (item != null)
      {
        string templateFile = string.Format("Templates/{0}", 
                                            Properties.Settings.Default.AppId + ".tmpl");
        if (File.Exists(templateFile))
        {
          FileStream fs = new FileStream(templateFile, FileMode.Open);
          DataTemplate template = XamlReader.Load(fs) as DataTemplate;
          return template;
        }
      }
      return null;
    }

  }
```

The DataTemplate is based on the XmlDataProvider and here I need to "inform" the Template which xml file it has to load because it is different for every tab:

```
<DataTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <DataTemplate.Resources>
    <local:StringToBoolConverter x:Key="StringToBoolConverter" />
    <local:StringToIntConverter x:Key="StringToIntConverter" />
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataProvider" XPath="func/parametri/param/BLOCKS"/>
  </DataTemplate.Resources>

  <Grid>
    .... controls ....
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is there a way to do it?

---

**EDIT**

**Substantially what I have to do is to have access to my Tab class into the TemplateSelector.**

---

Regards,
Daniele.

Answer (score 0):

if you could define your tabs like

```
public class TabFirst:ITab {}
public class TabSecond:ITab {}
public class TabBlup:ITab {}
```

viewmodel

```
public ObservableCollection<ITab> Tabs
{
 get { return _Tabs;}
 private set 
 {
   _Tabs = value;
    this.RaisePropertyChanged("Tabs");
  }
 }
```

you could get rid of the DataTemplateSelector and just definfe your datatemplates in your resources

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabFirst}">
  <view:TabFirstView />
<DataTemplate/>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TabSecond}">
  <view:TabSecondView />
<DataTemplate/>
```

and your content control would be just

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi @blindmeis, maybe I don't explain well what I have to do. I edited my post, moreover substantially my problem is to have access to my Tab class into the TemplateSelector.